# How to get a customer ID from event object (webhooks) in stripe using Django?

Tags: django, stripe-payments, webhooks

I can't find where is the the customer id when I receive an avent from Stripe webhooks after a transaction was made:

```
@csrf_exempt
def StripeWebhookView(request): 
 CHECKOUT_SESSION_COMPLETED = "checkout.session.completed"
   payload = request.body    
    sig_header = request.META["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"]
    endpoint_secret=''
    
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload,
            sig_header,
            endpoint_secret
        )
       if event["type"] == CHECKOUT_SESSION_COMPLETED:
       **customer_id_stripe = event["data"]["object"]["customer"]**
        print('customer_id:', customer_id_stripe)
```

I have tried to fetch the customer id by using this line of code:

```
**customer_id_stripe = event["data"]["object"]["customer"]**
```

but when I print

```
customer_id_stripe
```

it print

```
None
```

and to be honest, when I check out the  full object I recieved from Stripe this is what I get:

```
{
  "id": "evt_1MqMKgESXHNK1nmVaYJeR1PX",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2022-11-15",
  "created": 1679947678,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_test_a1A15S4eEOZc3WPfyTT5aJeGhhXRi5DK8xQiRnbgs8iG16rZ8oN032V8rm",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "after_expiration": null,
      "allow_promotion_codes": null,
      "amount_subtotal": 50,
      "amount_total": 50,
      "automatic_tax": {
        "enabled": false,
        "status": null
      },
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/discovery/",
      "client_reference_id": null,
      "consent": null,
      "consent_collection": null,
      "created": 1679947653,
      "currency": "usd",
      "custom_fields": [
      ],
      "custom_text": {
        "shipping_address": null,
        "submit": null
      },
# **"customer": null,**
      "customer_creation": "if_required",
      "customer_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": "IL",
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": null,
          "state": null
        },
        "email": "anon@gmail.com",
        "name": "asdasd",
        "phone": null,
        "tax_exempt": "none",
        "tax_ids": [
        ]
      },
      "customer_email": null,
      "expires_at": 1680034053,
      "invoice": null,
      "invoice_creation": {
        "enabled": false,
        "invoice_data": {
          "account_tax_ids": null,
          "custom_fields": null,
          "description": null,
          "footer": null,
          "metadata": {
          },
          "rendering_options": null
        }
      },
      "livemode": false,
      "locale": null,
      "metadata": {
        "product_id": "9"
      },
      "mode": "payment",
      "payment_intent": "pi_3MqMKeESXHNK1nmV0QTmMtnU",
      "payment_link": null,
      "payment_method_collection": "always",
      "payment_method_options": {
      },
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card",
        "link",
        "cashapp"
      ],
      "payment_status": "paid",
      "phone_number_collection": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "recovered_from": null,
      "setup_intent": null,
      "shipping_address_collection": null,
      "shipping_cost": null,
      "shipping_details": null,
      "shipping_options": [
      ],
      "status": "complete",
      "submit_type": null,
      "subscription": null,
      "success_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/success/",
      "total_details": {
        "amount_discount": 0,
        "amount_shipping": 0,
        "amount_tax": 0
      },
      "url": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 3,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "checkout.session.completed"
}
```

why i dont get the user's id ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customer is null here because it wasn't required that a customer be created for that Checkout Session (currently only Subscription Checkout Sessions require a Customer to be created). You can see `"customer_creation": "if_required",` in the event. With that set (which is the default), a customer is only created if it's required. To always create a customer in a Checkout Session, [you'll need to set](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer_creation) `customer_creation` to `always`.